# cannot disable dtrace restrictions, nvram protection and debugging restrictions in SIP in El capitan

Tags: osx-elcapitan

I have installed El Capitan recently. I have successfully booted in recovery mode in el capitan and have typed in `csrutil disable` command from terminal.....

rebooted but even after repeated attempts it shows that :

```
SIP protection enabled(Custom configuration)

Configuration:
Apple Internal: disabled
Kext Signing: disabled
Filesystem protection: disabled
Debugging restrictions: enabled
Dtrace restrictions: enabled
NVRAM Protections: enabled


This is an unsupported.......
```

I have spent hours but cant figure out the issue.

Why cant i disable the the last three restrictions even after typing csrutil disable in recovery mode in EL Capitan?

I have tried multiple times  and everytime i issue the CSRutil command in recovery mode; it says SIP successfully disabled; reboot for changes to take effect....

but after rebooting and loging onto normal mode when i check csrutil status: its shows the above status only..

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to disable parts of SIP while leaving others enabled.

If you run csrutil status, even while booted normally, you will see the component parts of it. Each of these can be selectively disabled by running one of the following commands while booted into Recovery mode:

```
csrutil enable --no-internal
csrutil enable --without kext
csrutil enable --without fs
csrutil enable --without debug
csrutil enable --without dtrace
csrutil enable --without nvram
```

NOTE the use of `enable` and not `disable`

You can disable two or more components by structuring the command as follows:

`csrutil enable --without kext  --without debug`

Answer (score 0):

To Disable/ReEnable:

Boot to Recovery Mode.

1. Hold <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at startup before booting to apple logo.
2. Click on top of Utilities.
3. Click on Terminal.

Then type these commands.

To ReEnable, just simply replace "Disable"
with "Enable".

---

Disable NVRAM protection

```
csrutil disable --without nvram
```

---

Disable DTRACE

```
csrutil disable --without dtrace
```

---